# CloudFront responds with 413 after AWS Cognito redirect

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-413

I have a React app built using [Serverless NextJS](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-nextjs) and served behind AWS CloudFront. I am also using AWS Cognito to do authentication of our users.

After a user successfully authenticates through AWS Cognito, they are redirected to my React App with a query string containing OAuth tokens (`id_token`, `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `raw[id_token]`, `raw[access_token]`, `raw[refresh_token]`, `raw[expires_in]`, `raw[token_type]`).

It seems that the query string is simply larger than AWS CloudFront's limits and it is throwing the following error below:

```
413 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.

Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app...

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: FlfDp8raw80pAFCvu3g7VEb_IRYbhHoHBkOEQxYyOTWMsNlRjTA7FQ==
```

This error has been encountered before by many other users ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244883/cloudfront-responds-with-a-status-of-413-request-entity-too-large)). Keen to know:

- Are there any workarounds? Perhaps is there a way to configure AWS Cognito to reduce the number of tokens that it is passing in the query string by default?
- Is it possible to configure AWS CloudFront to ignore enforcing its default limits on certain pages (and not cache theme)?
- What's the suggestion going forward? The only thing I can imagine is *not* to use AWS CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

After analysing the query fields that AWS Cognito sends to a callback URL, I was able to determine that not all fields are required for my usecase. Particularly the `raw` OAuth token fields.

With that information, I solved the problem by writing a "middleware" to intercept my backend system redirecting to my frontend (that is sitting behind CloudFront) and trimming away query string fields that I do not need to complete authentication.

In case this could inspire someone else stuck with a similar problem, here is what my middleware looks like for my backend system ([Strapi](https://strapi.io/)):

```js
module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        await next();

        if (ctx.request.url.startsWith("/connect/cognito/callback?code=")) {
          // Parse URL (with OAuth query string) Strapi is redirecting to
          const location = ctx.response.header.location;
          const { protocol, host, pathname, query } = url.parse(location);

          // Parse OAuth query string and remove redundant (and bloated) `raw` fields
          const queryObject = qs.parse(query);
          const trimmedQueryObject = _.omit(queryObject, "raw");

          // Reconstruct original redirect Url with shortened query string params
          const newLocation = `${protocol}//${host}${pathname}?${qs.stringify(
            trimmedQueryObject
          )}`;

          ctx.redirect(newLocation);
        }
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I had the exact same use case as you. Thank you so much for this snippet!